# JetBrains IDEA: how to disable diff highlighting in editor?

Tags: intellij-idea

I checked my project into GIT support and after that there are marks in editor showing me places I changed in file relative to the last commit (I think). It really slows editor. How to turn this off? I can't find the specific option in settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disable it except disabling the version control completely in Settings | Version Control.

If it slows down the editor (it shouldn't), please [file a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) with a [CPU snapshot](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-192).

Comment: Thanks. I will look. May be it's just because I enabled every single inspection I could find ;)